# Random Ordinal with dynamic count of object captured using Descriptor

Tags: javascript, loadrunner, truclient

I've managed to capture Object(s) that I want by using Descriptor
but I want to randomly click a button from the captured object.

[image]

is there a way to get how many object I got from the Descriptor so that I can use it to manipulate it on the Object Ordinal? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easier in standard HTML virtual user.  I recommend giving it a shot there.   You correlate for the href tags and then randomly select one to be pushed by in a web_url() statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use Utility function(lr_paramarr_random()).

//Capture all the objects

```
web_reg_save_param("c_object","LB=something","RB=something","ord=All",LAST);
web_custom_request(.....);
```

//It will automatically pick random object from the list of objects each time

```
lr_paramarr_random(lr_eval_string("{c_object}"),"Rand");
```

//random object click request

```
web_custom_request(...{Rand}...)
```